# Mi domandavo se fosse stato coniato un equivalente di "affordance" in italiano

Tags: word-meaning, translation

Mentre traducevo un testo in italiano ho trovato alcune difficoltà nel tradurre *affordance*, termine che non conoscevo neanche in inglese.
Mi domandavo se ci fosse un equivalente in italiano.

Answer (score 1):

È un termine piuttosto tecnico e specifico di certi ambiti come il design, quindi va visto se e come viene tradotto in testi specialistici. Non ci si può affidare a un traduzione comune,   se il testo che devi tradurre è di disclipline particolari in cui si usa questo termine.

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affordance

La cosa migliore è guardare qualche traduzione già esistente.

Io penso che in genere non si traduce, meglio lasciarlo in inglese, penso anche che in certi contesti, come il design, sia sbagliato tradurlo. Bisogna guardare i precedenti.

Ho il libro D. Norman, *La caffettiera del masochista*, che puoi vedere citato anche nella voce di Wikipedia sopra, che è un celebre libro di design, e lì il termine *affordance* non viene tradotto.

Ad esempio, nel capitolo *IV*, una parte ha il titolo *Affordance, significati e vincoli negli oggetti quotidiani*.